# How to get two names for two columns with id in a query? Innerjoin optional?

Tags: sql, database, sqlite

I have two tables in sqlite:

**names**

```
id     name
---   -----
1     Tyrion
2     Arya
3     Snow
```

**info**

```
id    otherID
---  ---------
2    1
3    2
1
```

**How I can get this result?**

```
2, Arya, 1, Tyrion
3, Snow, 2, Arya
1, Tyrion
```

If I do this query:

```
SELECT info.id, names.name, info.otherID, names2.name
FROM info
inner join names on names.id = info.id
inner join names as names2 on names2.id = info.otherID
```

I get only this:

```
2, Arya, 1, Tyrion
3, Snow, 2, Arya
```

This does not appear:

```
1, Tyrion
```

**How I can get the list of the optional field otherid?**

Comment: why mysql tag?? how it is related to mysql?

Comment: @JavaMan ups, corrected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Left join is the answer.

```
SELECT info.id, names.name, info.otherID, names2.name
FROM info
LEFT join names on names.id = info.id
LEFT join names as names2 on names2.id = info.otherID
```

You want to have all rows of `info` (left table in the join statement) regardless if there's an entry in the `names` tables (right side in the join statement).

Comment: LEFT JOIN is the solution, thnks!

Answer (score 1):

Try using LEFT JOIN

```
SELECT info.id, names.name, info.otherID, names2.name
FROM info
LEFT JOIN names on names.id = info.id
LEFT JOIN names as names2 on names2.id = info.otherID
```

Comment: RIGHT and FULL OUTER JOINs are not currently supported

Comment: Then use LEFT JOIN and which database are you used?

Comment: LEFT JOIN is the solution, thnks!